# href relative links broken in git hub pages

Tags: html, github, href

[link to website in GitHub pages](https://furqaan78621.github.io/odin-recipes/)   [git hub repository](https://github.com/furqaan78621/odin-recipes/)   when i pushed my code to git hub i tried to use git hub pages to display a simple recipe website i created but when i load the website it takes me to the index.html file and when i try to go to the lasagne recipe it says "error 404 there isn't a GitHub pages site here." here i dont know how to fix this and i just want to set up a place for all my future projects to be stored I have only just started programming so any help would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make href="https://furqaan78621.github.io/odin-recipes/recipes/lasagne.html"

or remove "../"

You should also rename lasagne.html to index.html to have less sub directories and contain all files for lasagna in a folder under recipes.

Comment: ill try this do i have to edit the code in vs code then commit and then push or just commit

Comment: i have changed the href but it still dosent work

Comment: my bad i tried again and it works now

Comment: Yeah, it usually takes a few minutes after for github pages to update rather than the actual repo